# how to filter through combobox in angular?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

Suppose I have a select that is used as part of a filter for a ngtable:

```
<select ng-model="search.id" id="">
                <option value=0>All</option>
                <option value=111>111</option>
                <option value=112>112</option>
</select>
```

The table and filters look like this in html:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="account in $data  | filter:search.accountName">
              <td data-title="'id'">
                {{account.account.accountId.id}}
              </td>
              <td data-title="'name'">
                {{account.account.accountName}}
              </td>

            </tr>
</table>
```

This is the filter:

```
$scope.idFilter = function(account) {
    return (account.accountId.id == search.id);
}
```

This is the json data:

```
var data = [{
      "account": {
        "accountId": {
          "id": "111"
        },
        "accountName": "Jack the Beanstalker"
      }
    },

    {
      "account": {
        "accountId": {
          "id": "112"
        },
        "accountName": "Mick the Stalkbeaner"
      }
    }
  ];
```

plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/do3Khx?p=preview

Comment: What is your question? I mean what is the issue?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/6S2Yh5zUhc6CEFfc3nvB?p=preview does this work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to filter based on a dropdown also, you can achieve it like this (although I'm not sure I understood correctly?):

just add this as another filter:

```
| filter:search.id
```

and in select options add '' as a value for the first line

```
<option value=''>All</option> 
<option value=111>111</option>
<option value=112>112</option>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6S2Yh5zUhc6CEFfc3nvB?p=preview

Does this work for you?